# Не отправляются стикеры aiogram 3

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram, python-telegram-bot

Делаю тг бота, используя версию aiogram 3.2.0. На других версиях проблем со стикерами не было. Для отправки их, использую самый обычный код:

```
f s > 0:
        if len(mails) > 1:
            await bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, '')
            await bot.send_sticker(call.from_user.id, stickers.SUCCESS_M)
        else:
            await bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, '')
            await bot.send_sticker(call.from_user.id, stickers.SUCCESS_S)
    else:
        await bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, "")
        await bot.send_sticker(call.from_user.id, stickers.FAILURE)
```

В файле stickers хранятся id стикеров. Исключений никаких не выдаёт. функция send_sticker просто игнорируется. Что делать в таком случае?

Я пытался использовать другого бота, один раз, когда произошла странная ситуация это помогло